# How to change grub to start in tty1, just disable graphics like on servers

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, graphics

I have some issue with my graphics, so i want to start in the commandline without using `nomodeset`. I just change them during boot, so that the changes are not saved.

my Grub-config look like this:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-eb4bd567-94>
        recordfail
        savedefault
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos1'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root eb4bd567-946d-4875-88c4-c05bb0be2657
        fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic root=UUID=eb4bd567-946d-4875-88c4-c05bb0be2657 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
```

I tried disabling the `load_video` and changed `gfxmode text` and removed `quiet splash`. I get an visible output, but it stops at an entry with "disk manager".
So what am I doing wrong? Basically it should like any server grub which do not start any graphical interfaces. I know that it is possible to start without activation xorg.

Thanks for your help and advice.

---

Edit 15.12.20 17:40

Okay I get the commandline running, but it stops still with `disk manager`. [Here is a Picture](https://pasteboard.co/JF3Qu51s.jpg) of the last activities before it stops.

Using Kubuntu 20.04

---

Edit 15.12.20 19:19

[Boot-Repair protocol](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9mQmY6wSVx/)

Comment: If you always want terminal: Uncomment #GRUB_TERMINAL=console from /etc/default/grub Or when booting change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash” to ”text”

Comment: Thx. Now I am sure to did I right, but still no more activities after `disk manager`

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? You show msdos partitioning? Most new systems are UEFI with gpt partitioning. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: It is a old system, a BIOS motherboard, Radeon RX580, 8GB ram, 6x3,0GHz CPU(amd). Using a dual-boot system. 
I do not get which detail you want to see, at the moment I can just boot using the `nomodeset` parameter. Trying to creat a Boot-Repair usb and adding the info.

Comment: I do not know AMD specific issues. I thought that older Radeon cards were just supported by a Radeon driver if newer AMDGPU driver not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To temporarily boot to console, reboot the computer and once you see the GRUB screen, with the first entry from the menu selected, press the "e" key. This allows you to edit the kernel parameters before booting.

Next, look for the line that begins with "linux" (use the Up / Down / Left / Right arrow keys to navigate); "vmlinuz" should also be on the same line. At the end of this line (you can place the cursor using the arrow keys at the beginning of the line, then press the End key to move the cursor to the end of that line) add a space followed by the number 3. Don't change anything else.

This 3 represents the multi-user.target systemd target which is mapped to the old, now obsolete runlevel 2, 3 and 4 (used to start and stop groups of services).

After doing this, press Ctrl + x or F10 to boot to console (text) mode.

From [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/01/how-to-boot-to-console-text-mode-in.html).

Comment: Okay it just show a single line `[ ok ] Hold .. finishes` after 5 minutes I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it by using service like this one, i guess.

[Change default login tty](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=231082)